# Substring in Java UDF

Tags: java, substring

I want to extract words in front of "Curncy" using substring and indexOf or by any other recommended way.

```
AED Curncy|0|6|UAE Dirham Spot|3.67300|12/12/2016|1.0000|N|USDAUD Curncy|0|6|USD-AUD X-RATE|1.385650|12/12/2018|1.0000|N|BGN Curncy|0|6|Bulgarian Lev Spot|1.720302|12/12/2015|1.0000|N|
```

I want values to be populated as:

```
AED
USAAUD
BGN
```

Kindly let me know how to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is with a very simple regular expression.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\w*) Curncy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "AED Curncy|0|6|UAE Dirham Spot|3.67300|12/12/2016|1.0000|N|USDAUD Curncy|0|6|USD-AUD X-RATE|1.385650|12/12/2018|1.0000|N|BGN Curncy|0|6|Bulgarian Lev Spot|1.720302|12/12/2015|1.0000|N|";

        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            matches.add(m.group(1));
        }

        System.out.println(matches);
    }
}
```

This will print the `List` of matches like so:

```
[AED, USDAUD, BGN]
```

More info on how to use regular expression [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This way using filter you can do it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.poi.util.SystemOutLogger;

public class StringUDF {

    public static void main(String... strings) {

        String s = "AED Curncy|0|6|UAE Dirham Spot|3.67300|12/12/2016|1.0000|N|USDAUD Curncy|0|6|USD-AUD X-RATE|1.385650|12/12/2018|1.0000|N|BGN Curncy|0|6|Bulgarian Lev Spot|1.720302|12/12/2015|1.0000|N|";

        Arrays.asList(s.split(Pattern.quote("|"))).stream().filter(stm -> stm.endsWith(" Curncy"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().map(stm1 -> stm1.replaceAll(" Curncy", ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```